# Kubernetes pod with readiness probe on Azure AKS check returns 404 http status

Tags: azure, azure-aks, readinessprobe

I have a Pod which listens to port 8000. When i add readiness probe and redeploy, the check fails with the message "readiness failed with http status 404"

I have the the values for readiness check set as below

```
timeoutSecond: 30sec
periodSeconds: 180
```

The check returns 404 when i describe my pod far before my ingress(Loadbalancer) starts listening. Or atleast i believe so since i see the LB IP in (kubectl get svc) comes after several minutes.

Comment: where is the question? your app responds with 404. what are we supposed to do?

Comment: Ok so if my app returns 404 when called via HTTP does that mean the probe will fail?
The pod when described shows Ready: False and  "readiness failed with http status 404" message.

Comment: Can you paste the yaml? Also, create another pod and curl the endpoint of the readiness probe. You get 404 there too? Finally, the probes are made by kubelet. It has nothing to do with the load balancer.

Comment: I have other pods which when curled over the service ip and container port gives a status 200. Does it mean that readiness check depends on the http status response code which when returned other than 200 is considered to be failed?

Comment: Any idea guys??